# Ionic 5 long press a ion-card for multiple card selection and getting some buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am building clone of google keep app in ionic. I want to select multiple ion-cards on long press and get a variety of buttons displayed on top. I don't have any idea of how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

firstable you should use a gesture library to catch long-press gesture. I think Hammerjs is fit to you. After the gesture catching you can simply add a class when longpress gesture with use ngClass. Here is an example for you;

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-5-long-press-gesture-example/188746

Comment: i have implemented long press using ionic gestures, but i still cant figure out how to multi select. to elaborate, I have multiple ion-cards on my home page, I want to select them when I long press on any one. Like we can select multiple photos in gallery.